# Send Email with attachment Asp-Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp, email-attachments

I'm making a form that sends an email with an attachment, my application works locally without problems, but when I run it from the server the email is not sent

I'm not sure if I should give a temporary folder to upload the file to the server, I just want the attachment sent, not saved on the server, what am I doing wrong?

My Model:

```
public class EmailViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Destino")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar un {0}")]
    public string Destino { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asunto")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe ingresar un {0}")]
    public string Asunto { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Mensaje { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase Upload { get; set; }
}
```

My View:

```
<h2>Enviar E-Mail</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("EnviarEMail", "OrdenCompras", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <hr />
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Destino, "Destinatario", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Destino, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , placeholder="gdiaz@mueblespangal.cl" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Destino, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Asunto, "Asunto", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Asunto, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , placeholder="Nueva Orden de Compra Muebles Pangal"} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Asunto, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mensaje, "Mensaje", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Mensaje, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , placeholder ="Comentarios"} })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mensaje, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Upload,"Adjuntar O. de Compra" ,new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="upload" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                    Enviar E-Mail
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

My Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult EnviarEMail(EmailViewModel emailviewmodel)
 {
     var mensaje = new MailMessage();
     mensaje.Subject = emailviewmodel.Asunto;
     mensaje.Body = emailviewmodel.Mensaje;
     mensaje.To.Add(emailviewmodel.Destino);

     mensaje.IsBodyHtml = true;

     if (emailviewmodel.Upload != null && emailviewmodel.Upload.ContentLength > 0)
     {
         mensaje.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(emailviewmodel.Upload.InputStream, Path.GetFileName(emailviewmodel.Upload.FileName)));
     }        

     var smtp = new SmtpClient();

     smtp.Send(mensaje);

     return RedirectToAction("VerOrdenCompra");
 }
```

My WebConfig:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="coambiado@gmail.com">
        <network enableSsl="true" defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="25"
                 userName="coambiado@gmail.com" password="******" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Comment: and updated my WebConfig, sorry! @Steve

Comment: that can be anything from a suppressed exception to a firewall or relay/routing problem. is there any error reported or logged?

Comment: I would leave it as an optional parameter ... it is not obligatory to send the E-Mail with an attached file @JonathanWood

Comment: "Error
An error occurred while processing your request." this my error @dlatikay

Comment: It is difficult to answer given that I only speak Spanish, but I understand that you ask me if you want the email to be sent with or without an attachment ... if that is your question ... it is not obligatory to attach a file for the user .. I explain myself well? @JonathanWood

Comment: @fytoahse: No, sorry.